# Sizeof returns unexpected result

Tags: arrays, c, function, sizeof

```
#include<stdio.h>

int test(int a[]) {
    printf("inside function test: %u\n", a);
    return sizeof(a);
}

int main() {
    int arr[10];
    printf("outside function test: %u", arr);
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(arr));
    printf("%d\n", test(arr));
    return 0;
}
```

Why does *sizeof* return a different result when *sizeof* is used inside a function to determine the size of an array compared to the result when sizeof is used normally (means without passing the array as an argument).

The address is same for both:

Inside the function test

```
printf("inside function test: %u\n", a);
```

And outside the function test:

```
printf("outside function test: %u", arr);
```

Why is the behavior of sizeof different when the array is passed as an argument compared to use of it normally without passing it as function?

In both conditions:

Inside the test function

```
sizeof(a);
```

Outside the test function

```
sizeof(arr)
```

Isn’t *sizeof* taking the base address of the array?
Aren’t both working as a pointer in both case? Why does test(arr) return the size of the pointer, but sizeof(arr) returns the actual size of array?

I googled and tried to understand, but I was not clear.

Comment: `int test(int a[])` is actually `int test(int* a)` - so you get `sizeof(int*)` - which is different from the size of an array

Comment: but how does sizeof(arr) differs from sizeof(a) since it is using same address

Comment: The type differs. Inside a function, array parameters decay to a pointer. That is, the size is size of a pointer.

Comment: ok thanks for your time but how is using sizeof(arr) is different. doesnt this decay to a pointer

Comment: To further add @UnholySheep 's comment, from the perspective of the compiler, you can pass array of `int` of any size regardless. There is no relationship between the declared `int arr[10]` and `int a[]` as parameter.

Comment: No, `sizeof(arr)` does not involve any array to pointer decay. `sizeof` is not a function, it's a built-in operator